# Printing an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array as such :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How would I do to have my array printed vertically ? (1 on the first line, 2 on the second line etc...)

Answer (score 3):

you just need to use `puts` method. `puts` can add a newline to the end of the output.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each do |i|
    puts i
end
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

or puts array directly.

```
a= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
puts a
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

You also can use `print` method, but it does not add a newline, but you can add line break manually( for your requirement, I think it is not necessary)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each { |i| print i; puts "\n" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach:

```
puts [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Also works:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each{|x| p x}
```

This works although it has been called insane and I accept that.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map{|x| p x}
```

Comment: I don't know why you'd use anything but the second option here if you're doing nothing more complex than printing each member on a new line.

Comment: Using `map` is insane here.

Comment: You should use `each` not `map` here. Using `map` to produce just some side effect during iteration is, at least, confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a splat:

```
p *[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is as follows.  This pulls each array element out to one string with newlines for vertical display then prints it

```
puts [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].join("\n")
```

I ran a quick performance test to see how this compares to the other options.  On a 100 integer array, I got the following performance:

- puts arr took 1.08 seconds
- arr.each took 1.22 seconds
- arr.map took 1.24 seconds
- puts *arr took 1.08 seconds
- puts arr.join("\n") took 0.44 seconds

Based on this, it looks like join is about 40-60% faster than the other options.  Granted performance may not be important to your usage :)